# Would the uncertainty principle apply to gravitational waves?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, gravitational-waves

The uncertainty principle is one of the most basic rules of quantum mechanics, but Quantum mechanics still has not been unified with general relativity, so would the uncertainty principle apply to gravitational waves?

Comment: There would be an uncertainty on the exact frequency, therefore the energy if you did a Fourier analysis of the wave packet that was recorded. it would not be the same as the wave function for a quantum particle. The wave equation there would define the probability of the position and energy of a particle. As far as i know there are no gravity particles such as the graviton that are accepted theory yet.

Answer (score 1):

The whole [Big Bang model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) of cosmology starts with an effective quantization of gravity at times before 10^-32 seconds. In addition, string theories are candidates for unifying all forces, and have quantization of gravity. Thus there is no reason at present not to accept that the Heisenberg uncertainty principle holds for [gravitons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton) too , the particles of gravitational waves.

Answer (score 0):

Uncertainty principle is part of quantum mechanics and is true with all quantum phenomena.

If you consider gravity waves a quantum phenomena, i.e. in terms of quanta (gravitons), then yes it would apply to GW and would also hold good.

GW was predicted by GR. As a GR phenomenon, GW are out of scope for uncertainty principle.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on precisely what version of the uncertainty principle you are considering you actually might not need to invoke quantum mechanics to argue that the uncertainty principle would hold for gravitational waves.

For instance, just because of the wave properties, there is an inherent uncertainty relation between the position and momentum of the wave.  I presume however that the proportionality constant here would not be $\hbar$ but rather $G$ though.

(DISCLAIMER: I'm rather unsure how the precise math would work out since momentum and position are usually defined with respect to an inertial frame, and not attributed to the space-time itself.)